# Zooming into a plot?

Tags: plotting

Consider:

```
tmax = 200;
βa = 0.9;
βi = 0.7;
b = (1.9/100)/(365);
ν = 0.2;
μ = (0.8/100)/(365);
ρ = 0.0001;
ξ = 0;
δa = 0.05;
δi = 0.09;
σ = 0.9;
τ = 0.1;
α = 0.01;
SAExR = NDSolveValue[{
    S'[t] == b*(1 - ν) - (βa *A[t] + βi *Ex[t])*S[t] - (μ + ρ)*S[t] + ξ *R[t],
    A'[t] == (βa* A[t] + βi* Ex[t])*S[t] - (μ + δa + σ)*A[t],
    Ex'[t] == σ*A[t] - (μ + δi + τ + α)*Ex[t],
    R'[t] == b*ν + ρ*S[t] + δa*A[t] + (δi + τ)*Ex[t] - (ξ + μ)*R[t],
    S[0] == 0.75, A[0] == 0.175, Ex[0] == 0.075, R[0] == 0},
   {S, A, Ex, R},
   {t, 0, tmax}];
{f1, f2, f3, f4} = SAExR;

st = Style[#, 15, Black] &;

Plot[
 {f1[t], f2[t], f3[t], f4[t]}, {t, 0, tmax}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Blue, Orange, Red, Green}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> st /@ {"Time", "Density"}, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[LineLegend[{Blue, Orange, Red, Green}, {"S(t)", "A(t)", 
     "I(t)", "R(t)"}, LegendFunction -> Framed], {0.85, 0.3}], 
 ImageSize -> 550]
```

The "red line" is not zero although very close and in the current it looks so. Is there a way to zoom into this? Showing it isn't zero?

Comment: Could you use `LogPlot`?

Comment: Why don't you just change the range of the Plot? Like try `{t, -.1, .5}`

Comment: Oh, you don't mean just at the origin. But you can do the same thing, like `{t, 10, 10.1}`. It would also help to remove the other functions so that they don't keep expanding the vertical plot range.

Comment: In the given code, `f3[tmax]` is negative and becomes negative around `0.75 tmax`. To keep this from happening, you need `AccuracyGoal` to be a bit greater than `-Log10[f3[t]]` (and `-Log10[f2[t]]`) throughout the solution. Use `AccuracyGoal -> 20` or higher and @Syed's recommendation of `LogPlot`.

Comment: `Min@f3["ValuesOnGrid"]` shows the minimum value of `f3` computed by `NDSolve`. That would show whether it stays above the x-axis.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a plot of the OP's solutions, scaled by and exponential factor `Exp[t/5]`. It shows that, contrary to the stated expectation, the functions do not stay positive:

```
Plot[{f2[t] Exp[t/5], f3[t] Exp[t/5]}, {t, 0, tmax},
 PlotStyle -> {Orange, Red}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> st /@ {"Time", "Density"}, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[
   LineLegend[{Orange, Red}, {"A(t)", "I(t)"}, 
    LegendFunction -> Framed], {0.8, 0.3}]]
```

[image]

As mentioned in the comments, the cure is to raise `AccuracyGoal`. The solution is usually kept within `10^-ag` of the solution, where `AccuracyGoal -> ag` (ignoring `PrecisionGoal`). If the magnitude of the solution is less that `10^-ag`, then the solution might become negative just from the allowable truncation error. With a high enough `AccuracyGoal`, Syed's suggestion of `LogPlot` will show the true solution remains positive (and decays exponentially).

```
SAExR = NDSolveValue[{S'[t] == 
     b*(1 - ν) - (βa*A[t] + βi*Ex[t])*
       S[t] - (μ + ρ)*S[t] + ξ*R[t], 
    A'[t] == (βa*A[t] + βi*Ex[t])*
       S[t] - (μ + δa + σ)*A[t], 
    Ex'[t] == σ*A[t] - (μ + δi + τ + α)*
       Ex[t], 
    R'[t] == 
     b*ν + ρ*S[t] + δa*A[t] + (δi + τ)*
       Ex[t] - (ξ + μ)*R[t], S[0] == 0.75, A[0] == 0.175, 
    Ex[0] == 0.075, R[0] == 0}, {S, A, Ex, R}, {t, 0, tmax}, 
   AccuracyGoal -> 24];
{f1, f2, f3, f4} = SAExR;

LogPlot[{f2[t], f3[t]}, {t, 0, tmax},
 PlotStyle -> {Orange, Red}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> st /@ {"Time", "Density"}, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[
   LineLegend[{Orange, Red}, {"A(t)", "I(t)"}, 
    LegendFunction -> Framed], {0.8, 0.3}]]
```

[image]